# After upgrading to Catalina, is there a way to remote control the Apple Music app on my desktop?

Tags: macos, ios, catalina, apple-music, remote.app

I have upgraded to Catalina and I have enabled Home Sharing.

I am able to connect to an airplay speaker from my desktop and from my phone.

I also have a set of non-wifi enabled speakers attached to the desktop.

From my phone, I am able to access the music library on my desktop, but I am unable to remote control the Apple Music app running on my desktop from my phone.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved in MacOS 10.15.2.

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2028?locale=en_US

> • Adds support for using an iPhone or iPad to remotely control the Music and TV apps on a Mac

Answer (score 4):

No - not today. Apple needs to update their iTunes remote so it works with the Music app in catalina.

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit. The `Remote` app is able to connect to `Music`. If I add something to the `Music` library it shows up in the Remote App. It also has some bugginess in that the `All Music` folder shows up four times, each with differing numbers of songs (9,575; 1; 0; 9,576). Given 9,575+1+0=9,576 it could be something wrong with the iMac library. But the `Play` control does not do anything.

Comment: I was encouraged to read your answer, but I no longer see my library in the Remote App since upgrading to Catalina.